# Why My path after upload image to public always store in c:\xampp\tmp\php3e93.tmp?

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to upload image in store function Laravel, and it's already success and already stored in database, but the path that always appear in this database is c:\xampp\tmp\php3e93.tmp, I'm already put it in my code to save in public, Although still not work. But in update function, it can work to save in public

How to solve this problem?

**my Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\AdminBank;
use RealRashid\SweetAlert\Facades\Alert;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class BankController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $banks = AdminBank::select('id','logo', 'bankName', 'type', 'noRekening', 'created_at')->get();
        return view('admin.bank.index', compact('banks'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:50',
            'logo' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
            'type' => 'required',
            'noRekening' => 'required' ,
        ]);

        $logo = time().'-'.$request->logo->getClientOriginalName();
        $request->logo->move('image\admin\bank', $logo);

        AdminBank::create([
            'bankName' => $request->name,
            'logo' => $request->logo,
            'type' => $request->type,
            'noRekening' => $request->noRekening,
        ]);

        Alert::success('Success', 'Data berhasil ditambahkan');

        return redirect(route('bank.index'));
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $banks = AdminBank::select('id','logo', 'bankName', 'noRekening', 'created_at')->find($id);
        // $banks = AdminBank::whereId('')->first();
        return view('admin.bank.edit', compact('banks'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:50',
            'logo' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
            'noRekening' => 'required' ,

        ]);

        $data = [
            'bankName' => $request->name,
            'type' => $request->type,
            'noRekening' => $request->noRekening,
        ];

        $banks = AdminBank::whereId($id)->first();

        if($request->logo){

            File::delete('image/admin/bank/'. $banks->logo);

            $logo =  time().'-'.$request->logo->getClientOriginalName();
            $request->logo->move('image\admin\bank', $logo);

            $data['logo'] = $logo;
        }

        $banks->update($data);

        Alert::success('Success', 'Data berhasil diperbaharui');

        return redirect()->route('bank.index');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function confirm($id)
    {
        alert()->question('Perhatian!','Apa kamu yakin ingin menghapus?')
        ->showConfirmButton('<a href="/admin-foresell/list/bank/' . $id . '/delete" class="text-white" style="text-decoration: none"> Delete</a>', '#3085d6')->toHtml()
        ->showCancelButton('Cancel', '#aaa')->reverseButtons();

        return redirect('/admin-foresell/list/bank');
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        $bank = AdminBank::whereId($id)->firstOrFail();
        File::delete('image/admin/bank/'. $bank->logo);
        $bank->delete();

        Alert::success('Success', 'Data berhasil dihapus');

        return redirect('/admin-foresell/list/bank');
    }

}
```

**my view**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-daftar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-notification"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-default modal-dialog-centered " role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h6 class="modal-title" id="modal-title-notification">Your attention is required</h6>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">

                    <form action="{{ Route('bank.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf
                      

                        {{-- Name --}}
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name"
                                value="{{ old('name') }}">
                            @error('name')
                                <p class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</p>
                            @enderror
                        </div>

                        {{-- TYPE --}}
                        <div class="form-group mb-3">
                            <label for="tipe" class="form-label ">Type</label>
                            <select name="type" id="" class="form-control form-select">
                                <option value="bank">Bank</option>
                                <option value="gopay">Gopay</option>
                                <option value="ovo">Ovo</option>
                            </select>
                            @error('type')
                                <p class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</p>
                            @enderror
                        </div>

                        {{-- logo --}}
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="logo" class="form-label ">Logo</label>
                            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="logo" name="logo">
                            @error('logo')
                                <p class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</p>
                            @enderror
                        </div>

                        {{-- Rekening --}}
                        <div class="form-group mb-3">
                            <label for="noRekening" class="form-label">No ( rekening / gopay / ovo)</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="noRekening" id="">
                            @error('noRekening')
                                <p class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</p>
                            @enderror
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Tambah</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**This is the screenshot in number 7**

[image]

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52006676/453348

Comment: still not working sir

Comment: `$request->logo` is the uploaded file, not the moved file, so you are saving the path to the temporary uploaded file ... you should be inserting the path and filename you moved the file to instead

Comment: Oh wow, thank u @lagbox I understand, and i change to this `'logo' => $logo,`. It's work